# Does the taglab directive require access to the internet?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, taglib

I'm currently trying to work out how to submit an HTML form to a spring MVC controller.

Most of [the tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/) I'm looking at want to use a

`<form:form>`

and require using the taglib directive

`<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`

However, the application I'm using needs to be run on an internal intranet environment, and so can't require access to the external internet to run.

Is there a way I can avoid this? (eg downloading the taglib as a library?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http://www.springframework.org/tags/form` is a URI, not a URL, i.e. it's used as an identifier for a given taglib, not as a a locator to go and download anything.

The taglib JAR has internal copies of everything it needs, you don't have to worry about anything being fetched externally at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Spring form `TLD's` and supported tag java files are part of `spring-mvc.jar`. So as long as you have downloaded them and have it as part of your application, you don't have to connect to internet. Hope this helps.